# How to stop a string from being cut off in Java

Tags: java, string, maven

I have a java code to call a REST API which returns a JWT token as a response. I send a GET call to the API and it will return a JWT token as a response. The token is being returned fine. However, I've noticed somehow the token is being trimmed.

I tried everything online and nothing seems to be working for me. Below is my code :

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL(proxyService.getProperty("proxy.url") + "/" + sessionToken);
    log.logText("Connection URL: " + url, logLevel);
    String readLine = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream in = ((URLConnection)conn).getInputStream();
        int length = 0;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
        while (-1 != (length = in.read(data1))) {
            response.append(new String(data1, 0, length));
        }

        log.logText("JSON String Result: " + response.toString(), logLevel);

    }

    conn.disconnect();
} catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

oauthToken = oauthToken.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
log.logText("OAuth2 Token: " + oauthToken, logLevel);

return oauthToken;
```

Regards,
Learnmore

Comment: I don't see where your return value `oauthToken` is generated or even declared.  Can you point out how this value gets set?

Comment: The oauthToken value is declared globally I removed the assigning of this value which was inside the while loop just to see how the response comes back.

Comment: `oauthToken value is declared globally` This could be a problem.  If the OAuth token can be changed anywhere (like calling `getOauthToken()` again) then the token could be getting changed and you'll have a bad token.  You should probably make the token immutable and return it, instead of a global.

Comment: (BTW, the OP did update their question with new information and showed how they set `oauthToken`, but a SO service outage ate the updated info.  Give them a change to repost it.)

Comment: You were assigning oauthToken *inside* the loop?  That sounds like it may have been the cause of your problem.  But we won’t know for sure until you repost the edit showing how it was assigned.

Answer (score 0):

As @markspace mentioned, please specify the data type for oauthToken (I believe it is of type String). Print the total String and then the length before replaceALL and after replaceALL. compare whats replace adds to the total length if yes then there is no issue of string getting trimmed.

Comment: I added the replace all to remove the double-quotes. When the token is returned it is inside the double-quotes which I don't need hence I used the replace all. Even without the replace all in place, the token is still trimmed when returned back.

Comment: Please try this out also give me the full sting that you are expecting Vs what you are seeing as response

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("userInput : " + userInput); 
         char letterGuessed = userInput.charAt(0);
         System.out.println("letterGuessed : " + letterGuessed);

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning *response* value to anything. I assume you should be assigning it to *oauthToken* variable.

Also please close the InputStream instance in finally clause, otherwise you will cause resource leakage.

Comment: I removed the assigning of the response just to see if the response is not trimmed which is not the case when the response comes back I could see it is already trimmed. This is how the token comes like
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4ZDIwMmEyYi1mODA1LTQyYjYtOTgxNy1mNTE3NGUzZ....."

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close `InputStream` first, to flush internal buffer.

```
public static String getOauthToken() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(proxyService.getProperty("proxy.url") + "/" + sessionToken);
    log.logText("Connection URL: " + url, logLevel);

    String oauthToken = readInputString(url);
    oauthToken = oauthToken.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
    
    log.logText("OAuth2 Token: " + oauthToken, logLevel);

    return oauthToken;
}

private static String readInputString(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        throw new RuntimeException("Not expected response code");

    try (InputStream in = conn.getInputStream()) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            int readBytes = in.read(b);

            if (readBytes == -1)
                break;

            buf.append(new String(b, 0, readBytes));
        }

        log.logText("JSON String Result: " + buf, logLevel);

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg

Thanks but tried the above and still the response is being trimmed (Mm8wOcn1c...
...(258 more)) when I look in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual application that I'm calling from is cutting off the response value. I shortened the length of the JWT token and it's not cutting it off. The application must have a limit for a maximum number of characters allowed in a string could be for performance reasons.